# unable to detect node names and freeze a fine tuned inceptionv3 model

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

Eventhough this question has been asked previously, i'd like to ask this question as I am new to tensorflow inceptionv3 model and I am unable to freeze my model and generate a Protobuf file(output_graph.pb).

I have a fine tuned inception v3 model with custom data set and got data,meta and index files. To freeze a model according to 
https://blog.metaflow.fr/tensorflow-how-to-freeze-a-model-and-serve-it-with-a-python-api-d4f3596b3adc
I needed to know the outputnode names. I tried to use this 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/544  for the nodes and got tower_0/logits/logits/xw_plus_b:0 as my output node. But when I use this node name to freeze a model, I am getting an error 
AssertionError: tower_0/logits/logits/xw_plus_b:0 is not in graph

So, is there any other way to find output node names? if so, can I use metaflow link model to freeze my model and get a output_graph.pb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the node names. I tried, tower_0/logits/predictions and it worked